# Neural network gives same prediction for each data point for diabetes.csv

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, neural-network, kaggle

I have a neural network in Python, but it gives almost the exact same prediction for each data point and I can't work out why this is. I have tried altering the features I use to make the predictions but I get the same issue. Thanks for any help.

I have a data file which looks like this:

```
Pregnancies,Glucose,BloodPressure,SkinThickness,Insulin,BMI,DiabetesPedigreeFunction,Age,Outcome
6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1
1,85,66,29,0,26.6,0.351,31,0
8,183,64,0,0,23.3,0.672,32,1
1,89,66,23,94,28.1,0.167,21,0
```

from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database?resource=download).
My neural network code is this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv", header=0)
print(data.head())
training_examples = data[["BloodPressure", "Glucose", "Outcome"]]
X = training_examples[["BloodPressure", "Glucose"]].to_numpy()
y = training_examples[["Outcome"]].to_numpy()


DIMENSIONS = 2
HIDDEN_LAYER = 20

# Set up the training data
# X = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
# y = np.array([[0], [1], [1], [0]])

# Set the number of epochs and the learning rate
num_epochs = 10
learning_rate = 0.1

# Initialize the weights and biases
w1 = np.random.randn(DIMENSIONS, HIDDEN_LAYER)
b1 = np.zeros((1, HIDDEN_LAYER))
w2 = np.random.randn(HIDDEN_LAYER, 1)
b2 = np.zeros((1, 1))


# Define the sigmoid activation function
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


# Define the derivative of the sigmoid function
def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return x * (1 - x)


# Train the network
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # Forward pass
    z1 = np.dot(X, w1) + b1
    a1 = sigmoid(z1)
    z2 = np.dot(a1, w2) + b2
    a2 = sigmoid(z2)

    # Calculate the loss
    loss = np.mean((a2 - y)**2)

    # Print the loss every 100 epochs
    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        print(f'Epoch {epoch}: loss = {loss}')

    # Backpropagation
    dz2 = a2 - y
    dw2 = np.dot(a1.T, dz2)
    db2 = np.sum(dz2, axis=0)
    da1 = np.dot(dz2, w2.T)
    dz1 = da1 * sigmoid_derivative(a1)
    dw1 = np.dot(X.T, dz1)
    db1 = np.sum(dz1, axis=0)

    # Update the weights and biases
    w1 -= learning_rate * dw1
    b1 -= learning_rate * db1
    w2 -= learning_rate * dw2
    b2 -= learning_rate * db2

# Make predictions on the test data
predictions = a2

# Print the predictions
print(predictions)
```

Comment: Does this occur when you're testing or training?

Comment: I ran your code, and it seems to give different predictions for different instances. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: I always get something like this (each prediction being the same): [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]
 [1.52563140e-64]]. These are the predictions after training has finished.